# How to implement offline reading in my android News app

Tags: android

I want to develop a "NEWS App" in Android.In that i want to include "Offline reading" also.
so any one please help me to how to do this.I currently using Rss reader.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you want to save an item for offline reading (either when you are notifed of an update, or when the user specifically requests it for an article, depends on your specifications), then save a local copy of the article ([Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)).

Every time the user clicks on an article to read it, first check whether you have a local copy: if so, open this one (offline, then). If not, try to get online (unless specifically forbidden, by user settings for example).

Also don't forget to add a clean-up feature to delete old articles, either manually (through a button in your settings) or automatically (expires after XX days).